# How can one analyse and/or eliminate performance variations due to memory allocation?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

I have a real-time application that generally deals with each chunk of incoming data in a matter of a 2-5 milliseconds, but sometimes it spikes to several tens of milliseconds. I can generate and  repeat the sequence of incoming data as often as I like, and prove that the spikes are not related to particular chunks of data.

My guess is that because the C++/Win32/MFC code also uses variable-length std:vectors and std::lists, it regularly needs to get memory from the OS, and periodically has to wait for the OS to do some garbage collections or something. How could I test this conjecture? Is there any way to tune the memory allocation to make OS processes have less of an impact?

Context: think of the application as a network protocol analyser which gathers data in real-time and makes it available for inspection. The data "capture" always runs in the highest priority thread.

Comment: Implement an allocator that you can control.

Comment: For performance-critical code, your best bet regarding allocation is to not do it. Pre-allocate and pool, so the OS has minimal control. Then your only worry is page faults.

Comment: @Cory - I was hoping to avoid that - the code is full of lists of vectors of lists, all of varying sizes. I'm not sure I can recycle the pre-allocated memory any better than the OS, so I'm hoping to understand how the OS goes about it.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to test is to not put your data into any structure.  *ie* eliminate whatever you suspect may be the problem.  You might also consider that the delays may be the OS switching your process out of context in order to give time to other processes.

If you are pushing lots of data onto a vector, such that it is constantly growing, then you will experience periodic delays as the vector is resized.  In this case, the delays are likely to get longer and less frequent.  One way to mitigate this is to use a `deque` which allocates data in chunks but relaxes the requirement that all data be in contiguous memory.

Another way around it is to create a background thread that handles the allocation, provided you know that it can allocate memory faster than the process consuming it.  You can't directly use standard containers for this.  However, you can implement something similar to a `deque`, by allocating constant size `vector` chunks or simply using traditional dynamic arrays.  The idea here is that as soon as you begin using a new chunk, you signal your background process to allocate a new chunk.

All the above is based on the assumption that you need to store all your incoming data.  If you don't need to do that, don't.  In that case, it would suggest your symptoms are related to the OS switching you out.  You could investigate altering the priority of your thread.

Comment: Thanks - interesting food for thought.